# how to store and print row number separated by comma in a for loop in a Java Program, I am using Java 4,looking for alternatives of List in Java 4

Tags: java, for-loop, iteration, legacy

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9bhj.png)I have multiple rows on billing screen application built on Java 4 and it doesn't support List(If I use List, it shows error that "Save project compliance and JRE to 1.5"). How do i store the row numbers for rows which have amount greater than 0 and print the row numbers separated by a comma. Eg: "Are you sure you want to proceed, The amount is > 0 for item numbers 1,4,7,8" Below is my code and I want to print row numbers in a warning prompt

```java
for (int i = 0; i < totalNoOfRows; i++) {


    String amount = dynamic value(eg 100);


    if(amount>0) {
        // Do some logic to store the row numbers where the amount is > 0
    }
}
```

```
*********Waring Prompt******
Eg:     "Are you sure you want to proceed, The amount is > 0 for item numbers 1,4,7,8"
```

Comment: Please provide your inputs on using alternatives of List as I am using Java 4 in my project.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` is part of JDK 1.4, so use that.
It is available since JDK 1.2. [Here are the docs](https://www2.cs.duke.edu/csed/java/jdk1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Comment: I am gettting error while using ArrayList , it says change project compliance and JRE to 1.5

Comment: What is your IDE?

Comment: My IDE is Eclipse